# how determine the number of arguments when using int main(int argc, char *argv[])

Tags: c

Say if I compile this into `./COMP`. 
If I write `./COMP "biscuits" "gravy"` then the answer is two. I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and I'm completely out of ideas.

Comment: Really? Any basic C book would tell you this. Not to mention the scores of hits you'll get with a few seconds of searching. People that post questions are expected to do at least some basic research first.

Comment: When you compile *what*?

Comment: `int tot_args = argc - 1;`, Now `tot_args` will have the number of arguments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int num_args = argc - 1;
```

Because the argc consists of the actual destination as its first char array (which is *argv[]). So you just subtract 1, eliminating the actual destination of the file you're running, and yup you got your num of args.